# How do I remove borders in a table?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am building a website in Wordpress using **WP Visual Bakery**. I used their RAW HTML element to create a table, but it renders with grey border lines. How do I remove these? I have attempted the other fixes suggested in other threads, but it doesn't work. I have included a screenshot at the bottom of this question. I'm sure the answer is very simple, but I'm VERY new to learning this. Your help would be much appreciated. The code I have used is below:

```
    <table width="542">
    <tbody>

    <tr>
    <td width="65"><img src="http://revenueresolutions.co.za/wp-
    content/uploads/2017/11/01-1.png" alt="One" width="50" height="50" />
    </td>

    <td width="492"><h2><span style="color: #73b9bb;">NEEDS &amp; GAP 
    ANALYSIS</span></h2></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><img src="http://revenueresolutions.co.za/wp-
    content/uploads/2017/11/02.png" alt="02" width="50" height="50" /></td>
    <td width="492"><h2><span style="color: #73b9bb;">STRATEGIC 
    PLANNING</span></h2></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><img src="http://revenueresolutions.co.za/wp-
    content/uploads/2017/11/03.png" alt="03" width="50" height="50" /></td>
    <td width="492"><h2><span style="color: #73b9bb;">TACTICAL 
    INITIATIVES</span></h2></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><img src="http://revenueresolutions.co.za/wp-
    content/uploads/2017/11/04.png" alt="04" width="50" height="50" /></td>
    <td width="492"><h2><span style="color: #73b9bb;">TECHNOLOGY</span></h2>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><img src="http://revenueresolutions.co.za/wp-
    content/uploads/2017/11/05.png" alt="05" width="50" height="50" /></td>
    <td width="492"><h2><span style="color: #73b9bb;">TRAINING & 
    DEVELOPMENT</span></h2></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><img src="http://revenueresolutions.co.za/wp-
     content/uploads/2017/11/06.png" alt="06" width="50" height="50" /></td>
     <td width="492"><h2><span style="color: #73b9bb;">RESEARCH & FUTURES 
    THINKING</span></h2></td>
     </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is what happens when I add any of the suggested code.

[Screenshot of element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmKmy.jpg)

Comment: I have already tried all the fixes suggested in the other post and none have resolved my problem.

Comment: What's the URL of your site?

Comment: try this :
table {border: 0!important;border-collapse: collapse;}

Comment: www.revenueresolutions.co.za

Comment: I have added a screenshot of what happens when I use the suggested code in a new answer as I can't seem to add it to this thread.

Comment: I've added the screenshot to my original question.